# hosting laravel app on windows shared godaddy server

Tags: php, windows, laravel, hosting

i have created my first hello world app using Laravel.
I also have a shared windows hosting on laravel.
When I ftp to the hosting, I get direct access to "/" where I put my index file.

How do I host this laravel app on this Godaddy hosting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general way of hosting laravel app is something like this :

- Put files from public folder to httpdocs, htdocs, www or other folder that is pointed to in your hosting environment (This is where index file resides)
- Put other files and folders such as App, Config ... Outside of that folder (You can put all folder and file as it is or you can create new folder and put laravel scripts inside that folder for easy handling in future)

So your structure can be something like this : (Note : this structure is based on plesk, So it might be different for you)

- Logs (Default hosting Dir)
- httpdocs (Public Dir, this is where you put files from your public dir)
- ..... (Other default hosting Dir)
- Script (For laravel scripts, you can name it anything you want)

As long as I know GoDaddy windows hosting has plesk as there control panel and so you can just host your site as I suggested above.

Now, in your case you only have access to httpdocs dir which is '/' Dir in FTP, Is because it is set as base directory for ftp user that you are using (I might be wrong here because of lack of details). So you can just change base dir for FTP user if it is permitted (Domain settings -> FTP Access) or you can create other user if you have slot left, or if you can't do that than just create zip and upload it using file manager from plesk.

**Here is screenshot of my laravel app hosted in plesk...**
[image]

And don't forget to edit your index.php file to change path, and setting permission to Storage dir.

**[Note : Never put your whole larvel app inside public dir because of security reason]**